# aumento tr y quiero que el numero de tr aparezca al instante

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Aumento *tr* con datos y que al instante los cuente.

Ejemplo

```
tr 1 = 1
tr 2 = 2
```

Así al instante en un *div*

```
$(document).ready(function aumento(){
    var nrows = 0;
    $("table tbody tr").each(function(){
        nrows++;
    });
    $("#nrows").html(nrows);
});
```

*html* que aparezca el resultado en este div

```
<div id="nrows" class="numero-carrito">0</div>
```

CON ESTA FUNCION INSERTO FILAS

```
 insertarCarrito(producto){
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>
        <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
    </td>
    <td>${producto.titulo}</td>
    <td>${producto.cantidad}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="borrar-producto fas fa-times-circle" style="color:blue;" data-id="${producto.id}" id="menos"></a>
    </td>
    `;
    listaProductos.appendChild(row);
    this.guardarProductosLocalStore(producto);
}
```

GUARDAR EN LOCALSTORE ESTA ES LA FUNCION

```
guardarProductosLocalStore(producto){
    let productos;
    productos = this.obtenerProductosLocalStore();
    productos.push(producto);
    localStorage.setItem('productos', JSON.stringify(productos));
}
```

Comment: Ese código que has puesto solo lo cuenta al cargar la página.  Si luego, de forma dinámica, agregas más filas o las quitas, debes incluir el mismo código en la función que lo haga, o bien te creas una función con ese código y la llamas al cargar la página y después de agregar o quitar filas.

Comment: No pongas código en los comentarios. No se ve bien y no ayudas a que la pregunta esté bien redactada y se entienda. Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para modificarla las veces que sea necesario.

Comment: MIL DISCULPAS GRACIAS POR LA SUGERENCIA SOY NUEVO

Comment: Mírate el último comentario de mi respuesta que he puesto, a ver si con eso ya te vale. Creo que si te va a funcionar, pero debes resituar la llamada a la función `recalcularFilas()` (que ahora está ejecutándose en la carga del documento) después de rellenar la tabla con los datos de localStorage.

Comment: SI ME FUNCIONA HERMANO GRACIAS

Comment: Perfecto!!   Te has podido ahorrar la nueva pregunta :-)  Primero pensé en otra solución más compleja y suponia cambiar demasiadas cosas en mi respuesta, pero luego se me encendio la bombilla y ya ves que ha sido relativamente fáćil. Saludos!

Comment: SI GRACIAS Y PENSAR QUE TENIA QUE LLAMAR A LA FUNCION ME AYUDASTE MUCHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazlo así mejor para realizar ese cálculo durante la carga del documento:

```
$(document).ready() {
  function recalcularFilas() {
    var nrows = 0;
    $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
      nrows++;
    });
    $("#nrows").html(nrows);
  }

  recalcularFilas()
}
```

para que luego, dentro de la función que incrementa las filas, puedas llamarla despues de hacerlo justo despues del appendChild() así:

```
insertarCarrito(producto){
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>
        <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
    </td>
    <td>${producto.titulo}</td>
    <td>${producto.cantidad}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="borrar-producto fas fa-times-circle" style="color:blue;" data-id="${producto.id}" id="menos"></a>
    </td>
    `;
    listaProductos.appendChild(row);
    recalcularFilas()
    this.guardarProductosLocalStore(producto);
}
```

Comment: gracias esta me funsiono

Comment: me alegro :-)  Si tienes una función para eliminar filas recuerda hacer lo mismo, es decir, llamar a la función `recalcularFilas()` cuando necesites actualizar ese valor

Comment: si lo tengo gracias me funciono pero como funciona con localstore cuando actualizo la pagina aparece 0 y cuando agrego otro sale el numero correcto  alguna sugerencia

Comment: Eso es un poco más complejo y cambia completamente el escenario de esta respuesta (no mucho, pero lo suficiente para que tengas que agregar una nueva pregunta con ese problema, lo siento).  Una vez ya tienes una respuesta que cumple tu pregunta, si luego cambias el escenario lo mejor es una nueva pregunta, pues quizás el que responde no sabrá como hacerlo y todo quedará muy lioso de entender por las siguientes visitas a la pregunta.

Comment: gracias igualmente por su respuesta y su recomendacion lo temare en cuenta reitero mil gracias

Comment: En tu supuesta nueva pregunta pon lo que hace la función `guardarProductosLocalStore` para que podamos ver el nombre de clave que usas durante el almacenamiento en localStorage, sinó sera más complicado ayudarte

Comment: Aunque ahora que lo pienso, igual lo puedes solucionar facilmente recolocando la llamada a la función `recalcularFilas()` después de que hayas rellenado la tabla por primera vez durante la carga del documento (sea como sea que lo hagas), en lugar de ponerla debajo de la función como está ahora, pues ahora no espera su carga, sino la del documento.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function aumentar(){
// obtener los tr que hay
var nrows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows.length ;

var table = document.getElementById("tabla");
// crea un tr
var row = table.insertRow(0);
// Inserta las celdas al nuevo tr
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// agrega los textosa las celdas:
cell1.innerHTML = "nueva celda "+nrows;
cell2.innerHTML = "nueva celda "+nrows;

 nrows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows.length - 1;
$("#nrows").html(nrows);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="aumentar()">aumento</button>
<table id="tabla" border="1">
<tr>
<td>celda default 1</td>
<td>celda default 2</td>
<tr>
</table>
<label>celdas:</label>
<div id="nrows" class="numero-carrito">0</div>
```

Comment: en los comentarios

Comment: tienes razón debería repasar